# C#, how to escape from subtract symbol in reference

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

How can i use reference .dll with an ' - ' symbol?
Because i've got an DLL named "Assembly-CSharp.dll" and i don't know how to use it because code is reading only 'Assembly'

Example.

```
using Assembly-CSharp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, you don't need to say `using Assembly-CSharp.dll` rather you should include the `NameSpace` defined by that dll using the `using` directive. So if that dll defines a namespace like `Assembly.CSharp.Drivers` then

```
using Assembly.CSharp.Drivers;
```

Comment: I can't do it like that.

Comment: I can't skip an reference.

Comment: @xScatta, am not sure what you are talking? Why you can't do that? what your assembly namespaces are? see the assembly in object browser and find out

Comment: It's an container.

Comment: Maybe easier, i have an container named Assembly-CSharp, and i need one method from it, but i can't do it because the subtract symbol is in the name of container.

Comment: @xScatta, still not sure what you saying cause you can't define a namespace with special character compiler will throw error in such case.